# Can anyone tell me why my divs are being ordered vertically and not horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code: [click here to see entire code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQULPJMJGPG5)

I am trying to build a horizontal array table. The data that is fed into the divs come from [my google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YrzAXbTiR19BSEFCzAluNAvSQRKwIRrVk4A6Lo-no5Q/edit?usp=sharing) and I appended that data into the div with `id="schedule"` . Every time I add a new row with topics in my spreadsheet, a new "topic" shows up in my HTML result, that is perfect but, my problem is that each div (topic) created is placed one below the other, and I want them to be one next to the other instead, horizontally. I also want to add a button to slide each div from left to right. ( This script is what describes better what I mean by this: [slide divs with a script](http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/1737/) ) I think I can do that myself once I figure out what is making my result go vertically.

In other words, I want to go from what I have now, which is this: 
[image: from_this]
To this:
[image: to_this]

I tried to apply the "display:inline-block" in the div with `id="schedule"` but it doesn't change anything.

Can anyone tell me what part of my code is making each "topic" be placed one below the other? And how do I need to change it to place them one next to the other horizontally instead?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" 
 rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">        
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/ 
1YrzAXbTiR19BSEFCzAluNAvSQRKwIRrVk4A6Lo-no5Q/1/public/values?alt=json-in- 
script&callback=doData';

function doData(data) { 
var results = [];
var entries = data.feed.entry;
var previousRow = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var latestRow = results[results.length - 1];
    var cell = entries[i];
    var text = cell.content.$t;
    var row = cell.gs$cell.row;
    if (row > previousRow) {
        var newRow = [];
        newRow.push(text);
        results.push(newRow);
        previousRow++;
    } else {
        latestRow.push(text);
    }

}
handleResults(results);
}

function handleResults(spreadsheetArray) {
for(var i = 1; i < spreadsheetArray.length; i++)
{   
    $("#schedule").append("<div id='img'><img src="+spreadsheetArray[i][0]+"         
width='300' style='border-radius: 8px;box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 
rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19) !important;'></div><div 
id='topic' style='font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;padding-left: 0px;'> 
<strong>Topic:</strong><span> "+spreadsheetArray[i][1]+"</span></div><div 
id='date'><strong>Date:</strong><span> "+spreadsheetArray[i][2]+"</span> 
</div><div id='time'><strong>Time:</strong><span> "+spreadsheetArray[i][3]+" 
</span>"+" a.m. California USA (GMT-7)</div>");
    $("#schedule").append("<div><label class='btn' for='modal- 
"+spreadsheetArray[i][7]+"'>More info</label></div> <input class='modal- 
state' id='modal-"+spreadsheetArray[i][7]+"' type='checkbox' /><div 
class='modal'> <label class='modal__bg' for='modal-"+spreadsheetArray[i] 
[7]+"'></label>  <div class='modal__inner'> <label class='modal__close' 
for='modal-"+spreadsheetArray[i][7]+"'></label>  <h2>"+spreadsheetArray[i] 
[1]+"</h2> <img 
src="+spreadsheetArray[i][6]+" alt='' style='float: right;padding-left: 
10px;' 
width='100%'/>&nbsp;<p><strong>Explanation: </strong>"+spreadsheetArray[i] 
[4]+"        
 </p><div id='count'><strong>Countdown:</strong><span> "+spreadsheetArray[i] 
[5]+"</span></div> </div></div>&nbsp;");
 }
}
$.ajax({
url: spreadsheetUrl,
jsonp: 'doData',
dataType: 'jsonp'
});
</script> 
<!----CSS------>
<style type="text/css">
.New-schedule {
margin: 12px; 
font-size: 14px; 
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
line-height: 1.8;
float:left;
}
#schedule { display:inline-block;}
/* --- modal ---*/
.modal {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-state { display: none;}
.modal-state:checked + .modal {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
transition: top .25s ease;
position: absolute;
top: -20%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 1em 2em;
height: 85%;
}

.modal__close {
position: absolute;
right: 1em;
top: 1em;
width: 1.1em;
height: 1.1em;
cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 2px;
height: 1.5em;
background: #ccc;
display: block;
transform: rotate(45deg);
left: 50%;
margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.modal__inner {
width: 90%;
height: 90%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
/* ---- Buttons --- */
.btn {
cursor: pointer;
background: #0099ff;
display: inline-block;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {background: #000000;}

.btn:active {
background: #038caa;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .2) inset;
}
p img {
max-width: 200px;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
</style>
<!----end CSS------>
</head>
<body>
<div class="New-schedule">
<div id="schedule"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant source code (Not just links) Thank you.

Comment: `Div`s are `block elements`. Try `display:inline-block` on them.

Comment: I tried to apply the "display:inline-block" in the div with `id="schedule"` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: My code is really long, that's why I pasted a link to it instead.

Comment: You are suppose to provide a _minimal_ working code snippet, reproducing the issue described, and it should be within the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Your approach**

Each item in your list is being rendered in a `<div>`. Divs are known as block-level elements, in other words, they take up the entire width of the container they are in. So that's why they are taking up the full width of the parent container and stacking down the page vertically. You can try making the `<div>` `display: inline-block` with a fixed width, but first you need to tidy up that code:

- Your list item `<div id="img">` isn't well named or even valid. An `id` can only be used once in a `document` and `img` isn't a nice name. Choose something semantic that covers the whole row, like `class="schedule-item"`.
- You've got a tonne of inline styling which can be moved out to a separate style rule: `.schedule-item { display: inline-block; width: 300px; border-radius: 8px; /* other inline styles... */ }`
- `handleResults` `for` loop starts at index of 1, which probably means you're skipping the first record.

**Better approach**

It looks like you need a carousel/slider plugin you can find online/GitHub. If you can find a plugin that gives you the desired look/behaviour, you'll need to match their HTML structure and the styling/interaction will be taken care of for you. For instance, [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html). You'd need to refer to their specific documentation, but the JS pseudocode would likely be:

- Initialize slider plugin on container `<div>` and request spreadsheet data.
- Loop over schedule items and use the slider plugin's API methods to insert/add slides.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQULPJMJGPG5)'s something that will get you started.

Comment: that cleaned up a bit the nested code in the script, and I applied and tested the inline-block to  ALL divs and nothing changed. They are still vertically. I think the problem must be in the `function doData(data)` part.

Comment: We could obviously go ahead and just do this for you with a plugin as a complete example, but I'm hesitant to do that as I think you probably need to "go back to basics" and do quite a bit of learning yourself.

Comment: I would appreciate if you do it for me, since I have been struggling with this for days, asking to all my friends, asking in Skype, nobody wants to help me and I am not a programmer, I didn't develop this code, It was actually a help from a friend, he developed it and I just changed minor things, so that's why I don't understand much. If you could fix my code I will understand what was causing it and  learn from that.

Comment: See my getting started helper.

Comment: I could finish it off but I don't exactly work for free haha. You'd need to [hire a freelancer](https://www.freelancer.com/get/benmccallum).